# Having problems running a basic PlayORM example on OneToMany with Cursor

Tags: playorm

I've been playing with PlayORM recently, and found it quite interesting and useful. Hence, first of all, thanks a lot for providing this.

However, I did have some troubles running a very basic example on OneToMany relationship with potential Cursor support. Briefly, I'm having three simple classes: Email, User and Test as below.

```
@NoSqlEntity
public class Email {
    @NoSqlId
    private String id;

    //getters and setters
    ... ...
}

@NoSqlEntity
@NoSqlQueries({ ... })
public class User {        
    @NoSqlId
    private String id;
    @NoSqlIndexed
    private String name;
    @NoSqlIndexed
    private int age;

    @NoSqlOneToMany
    private List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<Email>();
    //@NoSqlOneToMany
    //private CursorToMany<Email> emailCursor = new CursorToManyImpl<Email>();

    //getters and setters
    ... ...

    public void addEmail(Email e) {
        emails.add(e);
        //emailCursor.addElement(e);
    }
}

public class Test {
    private static NoSqlEntityManager mgr;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map properties = new HashMap();
        properties.put(Bootstrap.AUTO_CREATE_KEY, "create");
        String clusterName = ...
        String seeds = ...
        String keyspace = ...
        Bootstrap.createAndAddBestCassandraConfiguration(properties, clusterName, keyspace, seeds);
        NoSqlEntityManagerFactory factory = Bootstrap.create(DbTypeEnum.CASSANDRA, properties, null, null);
        mgr = factory.createEntityManager();

        Email e1 = new Email();
        Email e2 = new Email();
        mgr.put(e1);
        mgr.put(e2);

        User u1 = new User();
        u1.setName...
        u1.setAge...
        u1.addEmail(e1);
        u1.addEmail(e2);
        mgr.put(u1);
        mgr.flush();
        ... ...
}
```

OK, the scenario is simple and clear, and my Cassandra 1.2 environment is set up fine. Now, the problems:

1. When I use `List<Email> emails`, foreign keys for e1 and e2 are stored as columns in the row of u1 - this is exactly the expected behaviour. However, when I find the u1 object, `u1.getEmails()` is always an empty list, without e1 and e2 in it, although they are actually there in the db. Why?
2. When I use `CursorToMany<Email> emailCursor` instead, foreign keys for e1 and e2 never go into the row of u1 - this is abnormal, isn't it? Of course, in this case, when I find the u1 object, the Cursor does not have next().

BTW, I'm using PlayORM-1.7-snapshot, any tips and suggestions are very appreciated!

Lu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the good words about PlayORM.
Few things:
1. How you are getting your u1 object? I mean which method you are using?
2. Using Playorm command line tool, what result you are getting for the query
"select * from User"
OR
select * from User where id = "u1"?

3.There is a test case "testIndependentAddsAreCumulativeForCursor" in TestOneToMany.java. Is that running fine in your environment? If that is running fine, then please share your complete code.

Comment: Well, it was such a relief that the thing worked! Your test suite may not reflect this issue, as by default you use a in-memory db with 0ms delay. However, I used a real Cassandra cluster in a Cloud, which suffers from potentially tens ms of delay. Hence, the trick was simply not to retrieve the objects immediately. BTW, so it means mgr.flush() is unblocked?

Comment: You can run your tests with Cassandra as Dean mentioned in his answer. Also, not sure what do you mean by "flush() is unblocked".. Could you please elaborate a little more.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you can do if playing with PlayOrm is run the entire test suite and play in there as well(check out the entire project and in eclipse right click on com.alvazan.test and run all the tests).....NOTE: change FactorySingleton.java from IN_MEMORY to CASSANDRA to run against a local cassandra.

Once you have done that you can look at TestOneToMany.java which does the whole example you are talking about and all tests pass for that.  If any fail, let us know.

On CursorToMany, this is a special case in which the developer does NOT want to store potentially 100,000 or 1,000,000 relationships to the Emails in the same row since reading would result in reading in all 1 million foreign keys all the time.  Instead, CursorToMany throws it in an index row.  This allows reading of batches of the relationships at a time instead.  We have an entity on our project using this as it is related to 80,000 other entities and we don't want 80,000 columns read in every time we read the one entity.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Thanks Dean. I'm aware of the test suite, and I'm sure they will probably run well, although I haven't tried yet. I'm writing my own example codes, because I feel it helps me understand things quicker, and of course, integrates well with my existing Cassandra knowledge.

An important thing I learnt from your feedbacks is that the Cursor does not store FKs in the oringinal row, which is a design feature of PlayORM. Hence, what I have observed at Cassandra level are all normal, and the only problem I need to dig deeper is why I'm not getting the object references back - will post more later on.

Comment: cool, sounds good.  it is good to run the test suite so you can compare on what is going wrong with your code ;).  Sometimes it is faster to debug the issue when you have a reference example that works to find the typo ;).  good luck.